Intercepting OutOfMemoryErrors with JVM agent
I am trying to write an agent with ByteBuddy that would intercept the construction of java.lang.OutOfMemoryError and call my static method on that occasion. The target intention is to propagate information about Java errors in Prometheus metrics in a reliable way.
Example code:
public class OOMAgent {
    private static final Method HANDLE_OOM;

    static {
        try {
            HANDLE_OOM = OOMAgent.class.getDeclaredMethod("handleOOM");
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            throw new EvitaInternalError("!!! OOMAgent initialization failed !!!", e);
        }
    }

    public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) {
        if (HANDLE_OOM != null) {
            new AgentBuilder.Default()
                .type(named("java.lang.OutOfMemoryError"))
                .transform(
                    (builder, typeDescription, classLoader, javaModule, protectionDomain) -> builder
                        .constructor(any())
                        .intercept(SuperMethodCall.INSTANCE.andThen(MethodCall.invoke(HANDLE_OOM)))
                )
                .installOn(inst);
        }
    }

    public static void handleOOM() {
        System.out.println("!!! OOM !!!");
    }

}

I'm using Java, ByteBuddy 1.14.14, and have the following information in my MANIFEST.MF file
Can-Redefine-Classes: true
Can-Retransform-Classes: true
Premain-Class: io.evitadb.externalApi.observability.agent.OOMAgent

The OOMAgent class is called correctly and the agent is "installed" (no exception is thrown). But when the exception occurs, the handleOOM method is not called.
Can you spot something obviously wrong or give me some hints on how I could "debug" such an agent to find out what's wrong?
Maybe the Java classes are somehow protected? I am also using the Java 9 module system - could there be some kind of "visibility" problem?
Final solution:
I have working solution in this class.
In order to propagate information to my own classes, I was forced to create intermediary class ErrorMonitor that connects the callback from error / exception construction with Prometheus metrics and my liveness probe via. later injected consumer lambda. The class needs to be injected into the bootstrap classloader in order to be visible by the error constructors.
Because I want to intercept multiple errors by single advice and propagate the type of the exception to the metrics label, I need to use @OnMethodExit annotation where the @Advice.This annotation on input arguments is working (this is not possible for @OnMethodEnter).
The ErrorMonitor class ends up being loaded twice - once in bootstrap classloader and second in the application classloader. This means I had to inject consumers into both of them, which is visible in class ObservabilityManager.java.

If you have read my answer mentioned in update #1, you should know that OOMAgent is not on the bootstrap classpath, i.e. the bootstrap class you are trying to modify will be unable to find it. The other answer and the linked GitHub repository code also show what you can do to change that.

Your approach to modify ther bootstrap exception class might not be necessary, though. If the OOM error is propagated into your application code, you can let your agent handle it there. BTW, what is your exception handler really meant to do, other than just print a message? This question seems to be an instance of the XY problem, focusing on how you think you should solve your problem rasther than describing what you actually want to achieve. Chances are, that there are better alternatives.

@kriegaex, you're right. Sometimes it might not be necessary. But in my case I'm trying to create a reliable "liveness" probe for the Docker/Kubernetes health check and this approach seems beneficial.
The error could be thrown in several places, so I'd need to have multiple "catch" places. Otherwise, I might miss the problem or the error would be caught in external libraries I don't control.

Did you mean something like this?
import net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent;
import net.bytebuddy.agent.builder.AgentBuilder;
import net.bytebuddy.asm.Advice;
import net.bytebuddy.asm.Advice.OnMethodEnter;
import net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector;

import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;

import static net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers.*;

public class BootstrapOOMAgent {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    premain("dummy", ByteBuddyAgent.install());
    throw new OutOfMemoryError("uh-oh!");
  }

  public static void premain(String arg, Instrumentation instrumentation) {
    ClassInjector.UsingUnsafe.Factory factory = ClassInjector.UsingUnsafe.Factory.resolve(instrumentation);
    AgentBuilder agentBuilder = new AgentBuilder.Default();
    agentBuilder = agentBuilder.with(new AgentBuilder.InjectionStrategy.UsingUnsafe.OfFactory(factory));

    agentBuilder
      .disableClassFormatChanges()
      .with(AgentBuilder.RedefinitionStrategy.RETRANSFORMATION)
      .ignore(none())
      .ignore(nameStartsWith("net.bytebuddy."))
      .type(is(OutOfMemoryError.class))
      .transform((builder, typeDescription, classLoader, module, protectionDomain) -> builder
        .visit(
          Advice
            .to(MyAdvice.class)
            .on(isConstructor())
        ))
      .installOn(instrumentation);
    }

  public static class MyAdvice {
    @OnMethodEnter
    public static boolean before() {
      System.out.println("!!! OOM !!!");
      return true;
    }
  }
}

Console log:
!!! OOM !!!
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: uh-oh!
  at BootstrapOOMAgent.main(BootstrapOOMAgent.java:37)

Quickly adapted from my answer here.
Try it on JDoodle.
